# Copy&Paste cells if identifiers match in 1st column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in dire need for code that will copy & paste newly extracted data into a tracking worksheet, based off of matching numbers in the first column.

I have two worksheets, "Registry" and "Sheet2". Registry is used for tracking, Sheet2 has new data I want to transfer into Registry. 
I want the insurance type data (col B) from Sheet2 to be copied and pasted into the insurance type column in Registry (col E). But I need it to match up with the ID's in col A because my extraction doesn't include all ID's that I have listed in Registry.

If helpful, the range of cells w/ data in Registry is row2:row177; range of cells w/ data in Sheet2 is row2:row174

I appreciate all the help, let me know if I wasn't clear enough or if you need any more info.

Thanks,
Kyle

```
Sub updateins()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Registry").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To Sheet1LastRow
        For i = 2 To Sheet2LastRow
            If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("Registry").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Registry").Cells(i, 5).Value
            Else
            End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a code for me site. Please post any attempts, test data and expected output in your original question and let us know what specifically is the error. SO is a place where a community can help with problems in existing code.

Comment: Sorry about that, here's what I have done. I can't get anything to transfer over.

Comment: Just copy and paste the code directly into the original post using the edit.  Then highlight it and press Ctrl-k.  If you are unable to format it properly then just paste the code, someone will help format it properly.

Comment: So what is wrong with the code?

Comment: When I run it, nothing happens. I put in Option Explicit and re-ran, then an error message came up saying Compile Error: Variable not defined and highlighted Sheet1LastRow.

Comment: You need to declare both last row variable if you are going to use `Option Explicit`  so add the `Dim Sheet1LastRow as Long` and `Dim Sheet2LastRow as Long`  But that is not your problem with nothing happening.  You need to check the data for spaces and other non printable characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem might be. The code is working fine for me. Here are just a few minor adjustments as proposed:

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateins()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Sheet1LastRow As Long
Dim Sheet2LastRow As Long

Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Registry").Range("A" & Worksheets("Registry").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox "Comparing rows 2 through " & Sheet1LastRow & " on 'Sheet2'" & Chr(10) & _
    "with rows 2 through " & Sheet2LastRow & " on 'Registry'."

For j = 2 To Sheet1LastRow
    For i = 2 To Sheet2LastRow
        If UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value)) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Registry").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then
            Worksheets("Registry").Cells(j, 5).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

I merely added a MessageBox to make sure that both last rows are correctly determined through column `A`.

Comment: Thank you @Ralph. I ran the code and it did remove the data from Sheet2, but it did not copy over to "Registry", I don't see the data anywhere, maybe I did not define my R&C properly?

Comment: There is no copying over to the sheet Registry. There is only one line of VBA copying over from Registry to Sheet2. So, judging by your comment everything works add is should.

Comment: I see what happened, I had it completely backwards -- needed to copy over from Sheet2 to Registry (I'm very new to this incase it's not that obvious). I switched the sheets around and it works perfectly. Can't thank you enough @Ralph and Scott.

Comment: @kfire35 I am glad it works and (even more so) that you learned something along the way. We always strive here to help people understand rather than just provide the solution for them.